# How to apply intermediate value theorem to this quantity?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, mean-value-theorem

Let $N\in\mathbb{N}$ with $N\ge 2$ and $s, p\in\mathbb{R}$ with $s, p>1, p^*=Np/(N-p)$. Let $(x_n)_n$ be a sequence such that $x_n\to x_0$. Consider the quantity
$$\frac{1}{(s+1)^{p-1}}(x_n^{p(s+1)}-x_0^{p(s+1)})- (x_n^{p^*(s+1)}-x_0^{p^*(s+1)}).$$
During the math class we said that the above quantity is equal to
$$p(s+1)\left(\frac{\sigma_n^{p(s+1)-1}}{(s+1)^{p-1}}-\frac{N\tau_n^{p^*(s+1)-1}}{N-p} \right)(x_n-x_0)$$
for some $\sigma_n, t_n$ between $x_0$ and $x_n$ by the intermediate value theorem.

Could someone please explain me why it is true?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you sure you mean the intermediate value theorem and not the mean value theorem?

If you define $F_1(x)=x^{p(s+1)}$ and $F_2(x)=x^{p^*(s+1)}$, then these functions are differentiable assuming $N\geq p$ in any interval. In particular, for any $n$ there exists $\sigma_n\in (x_0 ,x_n)$ and $\tau_n\in (x_0,x_n)$ such that

$$ F_1'(\sigma_n)\cdot(x_n-x_0)=  \sigma_n^{p(s+1)-1} \cdot p(s+1)$$
and
$$ F_2'(\tau_n)\cdot(x_n-x_0)=  \tau_n^{p^*(s+1)-1} \cdot p^*(s+1)= \tau_n^{p^*(s+1)-1}\cdot p(s+1) \cdot \frac{N}{N-p}.$$